# How do I remove default windows items from the "open with" context menu?

Tags: windows-registry, regedit, windows-8.1-preview

[image]

The things in the image I have crossed out are the ones I want to remove.
I have already tried the various NirSoft utilities, none of them will remove the default windows items.

I've also tried regedit but editing the openwithlist entries still didn't prevent the default entries from showing up in the "open with" menu.

How do I kill these things for good?

Comment: Why would you want to? Anyway, I think Windows always shows every app he knows that can open the file.

Comment: relevant [kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258860) but not to this version of windows

Comment: Because I'm obsessive compulsive about reducing clutter. I never use these programs, I never want to see them.